# PrimeFaces 3.0 - How do I override the default opacity of a dialog overlay?

Tags: java, css, dialog, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using PrimeFaces 3.0 and JSF 2.0. In my webapp, I display a modal dialog over the page when the user's browser has been idle for a certain length of time and this triggers a session invalidation on the server side via an Ajax call. On the browser, the modal dialog displays a simple message that the session is terminated due to exceeding the idle time limit. This all works fine (see screenshot).

***EDIT: Updated with "appendToBody" fix***

[image]

Here is the code from my Facelet page:

```
    <p:idleMonitor timeout="#{initParam[clientSideIdleThreshold]}">
        <p:ajax
            event="idle"
            listener="#{logoutBean.idleListener}"
            oncomplete="idleDialog.show()" />
        <p:ajax
            event="active"
            listener="#{logoutBean.activeListener}" />
    </p:idleMonitor>
    <p:dialog
            header="Session Exceeded Idle Limit"
            widgetVar="idleDialog"
            modal="true"
            fixedCenter="true"
            closable="false"
            draggable="false"
            resizable="false"
            appendToBody="true"
            height="200"
            width="400">
        <h:outputText value="Session Terminated" />
    </p:dialog>
```

**What I want to do is override the default opacity of the PrimeFaces dialog overlay and make it more opaque. Does anyone know how to do this?**

I'm hoping that this can be accomplished by putting some CSS in the right place because I would ***really*** like to avoid writing any JavaScript to accomplish this.

The target browsers for the user environment are IE 6 and 7.

Comment: Where is your site? It's most likely a CSS property but we can't tell you until we see how it's built :)

Comment: Are you sure this dialog is modal (modal='true')? It looks like there is no overlay at all.

Comment: The site is on a private network unfortunately. The CSS used is packaged with the PrimeFaces 3.0 distribution, which relies heavily on jQuery UI Themeroller styles.

Comment: The overlay is pale blue on top of a white background. It is very transparent which is why I want to increase the opacity.

Comment: To change anything similar to this, simple start Chrome and press ctrl+shift+I, or install firebug in firefox, or press F12 (i think) in IE for developer tools. Then select the element you wish to change (in this case you would select the overlay) and see what classes are applied to the object. Then you can simply override that class like Fortega suggests.

Comment: Are you using p:layout? Can you replicate the behavior at modal dialog in online showcase of PrimeFaces? Can you try appendToBody="true" on dialog.

Comment: I am using a `<p:layout>`. The code shown above is located inside the center layout panel. I just added `appendToBody="true"` and that fixed the problem of the dialog box being displayed under the overlay. It did not fix the problem of the opacity setting not working under IE 7 (per Fortega's solution below).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fortega's answer was correct for some browsers, but for IE 7 you need to use the following CSS:

```
.ui-widget-overlay {
    filter:alpha(opacity=80);  /* works in IE 7 */
    opacity: 0.8;  /* works in Firefox */
}
```

According to [www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp) the opacity CSS attribute is non-standard but is proposed for inclusion in CSS3.

Answer (score 6):

in your css:

```
.ui-widget-overlay {
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

or some other value :)

But you need to be sure the dialog you are showing is modal(`<p:dialog modal="true"`), otherwise no overlay will be shown.

Comment: This works in Firefox, but not in IE 7 (which is the target browser for the user environment). I'll play around with it some more and see if I can find the problem. I am using `modal="true"` but it keeps displaying the modal box under the overlay. I can live with this for a simple notification like my idle message, but obviously you can't use a form dialog that is covered by an overlay. I thought this might be a defect in the PrimeFaces 3.0 snapshot, but maybe I'm doing something else wrong.